# Angular2 - load AppComponent in the "/" without any other component (Heroes Tutorial)

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

To ask my question I'll use as example the official [angular.io](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html) ***Heroes tutorial***.

(It is the result of the point 6.Routing - Tutorial).

When you do the **`npm start`** on the console, the HTML of AppComponent is loaded, but `/dashboard` is also loaded by default (When the URL is `http://localhost:3000` it is automatically redirected to `http://localhost:3000/dashboard`).

My question is: When you introduce `http://localhost:3000`, Is possible to only load HTML AppComponent and don't redirect automatically to `dashboard`?

I have tried to remove from **app.routing.ts**

```
{
  path: '',
  redirectTo: '/dashboard',
  pathMatch: 'full'
},
```

but then I get may errors like `EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes: ''`.

The official plunker is: https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/toh-5/ts/plnkr.html.

Thanks!.

Answer (score 0):

This is only because of your router. If you manage correctly your application, you can make it load a component first, and then choose what you load in your router-outlet. 
Here you only need to create a route with a component to load, instead of a redirecting to another URL route.

Basically, for angular, the URL start after http://localhost:3000/ and then by default the route path is '' unless you tell the router to navigate to a specific url.

You need to do something like that :

```
{ path: '', component: DashboardComponent },
```

**EDIT after plunkr :**

Change these code parts in the plunkr to see what you expect I believe.

**in app.component.ts**

```
<nav>
  <a routerLink="/" routerLinkActive="active">Dashboard</a>
  <a routerLink="/heroes" routerLinkActive="active">Heroes</a>
</nav>
```

**in app.routing.ts**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: DashboardComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'detail/:id',
    component: HeroDetailComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'heroes',
    component: HeroesComponent
  }
];
```

As I said in my first answer, when you start your app you will get to this url : "http://localhost:3000/". Your first component will be loaded with no url attached to it, that's why the path is empty.

```
{
  path: '',
  redirectTo: '/dashboard',
  pathMatch: 'full'
},
```

Your first piece of code tells the router to redirect on the url "/dashboard" when you are on the "/" url.
I only changed it to directly load the component Dashboard with no url.

```
{
  path: '',
  component: DashboardComponent
},
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm starting with angular2. I don't understant why you put path: ' ' and load component: DashboardComponent. What I want is not to load dashboard but I understand that your code loads it.

Comment: Add the code associated with your router so we can see more of the app in order to properly explain you ;) It's fine dw.

Comment: My code is 100% the same as you can find on the plunker I gave in the question.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but this is not exacly what I meant. I want not to load the **app/dashboard.component.html** at the start. I only want to load the dashboard when I click a button, not when the url is /.

Comment: Alright, so I finally understand what you really want, and unfortunetaly you can't here. Indeed, the way to make what you want work would have been to delete this specific piece of code, but when your component have a router-outlet, you have to manages the routes. 
In order to get what you want, you need to change the way the components are loaded to make it possible.
Here you indeed manage the routes /dashboard and /heroes but not the empty route which is linked to nothing if you don't redirect to another route.
I need my workspace PC to show you a working example, tomorrow if you want ^^

Comment: An example would make me extremely happy. If it doesn't matter to you. :).

Comment: Well I would be really happy to do it, but unfortunately I'm quite busy these days, I'll try to look into it pretty soon.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because  **router-outlet** is used in **AppComponent**. When you run your app, **AppComponent** comes into picture and because it has **router-outlet**, it requires at least one default view. In your case it is **dashboard**.

You tried to remove it and so you removed default set route. Default route needs to be present. If you remove it, angular router will throw an error.

router-outlet cannot be empty. You have to provide one view anyhow.

So with **AppComponent** html view, you will also have some other view in **router-outlet**.

So what you can do is

1) remove **roter-outlet** from **AppComponent**.

2) from **AppComponent Code** try to navigate to dashboard route. Somewhere in code, lets say in any buttons click event eg. `this.router.navigate['/dashboard']`

Comment: Will I have to remove this: **routerLink="/dashboard"** and add this: **<button (click)="goToDashboard()">** and inside this method the code you have given me? Anyway, what happens with **redirectTo** from app.routing.ts?

Comment: Yes you have to remove routerLink portion n use click event. You dont require default route to declare.

Comment: I tried what you said but console get some errors. http://plnkr.co/edit/LBIKYare1pIH93ZIyZYe?p=info